# Why is my Nikon Coolpix s550 not detected by Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, camera

I am trying to move photographs from Nikon Coolpix s550 camera to a shiny new MacBook. I just connect a cable into a camera and usb port and then nothing happens on both sides.

Any ideas how to make it working?

Answer (score -1):

Is the camera on? Is it set to share it's photos using USB? (Some cameras require you to press the Playback button, however that's become increasingly rare)

Have you tried opening Image Capture or iPhoto (in the Applications folder)?

By default, Image Capture should open up and ask you what program you want to use to manage the camera the very first time but if this default has been changed that may explain why nothing happened.

Answer (score -1):

If the camera is recognized by MacOS, it will automatically start iPhoto, for example. If it is not doing that, then it could be because:

- The camera isn't turned on;
- The USB connection isn't right for some reason, or isn't connected properly;
- MacOS could not find a driver to load the camera device.

I own a Nikon Coolpix L16. The driver disc I got with it had drivers for OS X. It also had the Nikon Transfer program which starts automatically when I connect the camera to my MacBook and start it. If you still have the disc that came with your camera lying around, it would not hurt to take a look in it. It may contain drivers and assorted applications for accessing the camera on MacOS.

Answer (score -1):

I had trouble getting a camera recognized on my mini.  It turned out to be a USB cable problem:  unless the cable had a ferrite core after the connector, my camera wasn't recognized.  Nikon actually included two ferrite cores that clip on over the outside of a USB/AV cable, but curiously, did not supply the cable itself, with my D3100.  I suspect if you check your camera's manual, it'll specify the necessity for such noise-reducing attachments.